# Is there a Git Configuration for every repository?

Tags: git, version-control

Upon the advised message using git `push`, I earlier set:

```
git config push.default simple
```

Now, opening a **new** repository, I have come across the same warning message from git.

Is there a config for each different repository? If so, does this mean I have to run the above command for each different repository I begin working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, only the current repository's configuration is updated, but you can add a `--global` flag to put the settings in your global configuration (these are per user and go in `~/.gitconfig`).

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

Comment: For completeness' sake there is also a `--system` option for system wide configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, git uses both a per-repository configuration and a global configuration. This is so you can have separate configuration for separate repositories. To set a configuration value globally, use the `--global` switch.